# How do I add validators when creating FormBuilder groups from a data model?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

According to [the Reactive Forms documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#the-data-model-and-the-form-model), I can refactor my FormGroup definitions from

```
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required ],
  address: this.fb.group({
    street: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    zip: ''
  })
});
```

to

```
export class Address {
  street = '';
  city   = '';
  state  = '';
  zip    = '';
}

this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required ],
  address: this.fb.group(new Address())
});
```

If I create a form group from a data model, how do I add validators?

Comment: I think you can use mix match of observer pattern with regex in setters.
Like check the validity in setters of model

Answer (score 3):

According to [the FormBuilder source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/form_builder.ts#L44-L45), `group` takes a second `extra` parameter in which you can define validators. [Todd Motto has an article on how to use it](https://toddmotto.com/reactive-formgroup-validation-angular-2) which suggests the following:

```
export class Address {
  street = '';
  city   = '';
  state  = '';
  zip    = '';
}

this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required ],
  address: this.fb.group(new Address(), { validator: this.myValidator })
});

this.myValidator = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} => {
  const city= control.get('city');
  const state= control.get('state');
  ...
  if (allTheControlsAreValid) return null;
  else return { myCustomError: foo};
};
```

This allows you to validate the form group, but not the controls. If you want to set validators on the individual controls, you can set them programatically after the `formGroup` is created:

```
this.heroForm.get('address').get('city').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]);
```